# How can I get the matched delimiter from Java's Scanner?

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

Using the following code as an example (modified from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)):

```
 String input = "1 fish 2 fish red sheep blue sheep";
 Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*(fish|sheep)\\s*");
 System.out.println(s.nextInt());
 System.out.println(s.nextInt());
 System.out.println(s.next());
 System.out.println(s.next());
 s.close();
```

Is there a way I can work out whether it was `sheep` or `fish` that matched?

Comment: `String.contains ("fish")` ? or use regex Matcher

Comment: My use case is way more complicated than that unfortunately :) Besides `s.next()` doesn't return the token at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question - this can be done by not specifying the delimiter and using `next(Pattern)` instead:

```
String input = "1 fish 2 fish red sheep blue sheep";
Pattern animal = Pattern.compile("\\s*(fish|sheep)\\s*");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);

while (sc.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(sc.next());
    System.out.println(sc.next(animal));
}
```

Output:

```
1
fish
2 
fish 
red 
sheep 
blue 
sheep
```

**EDIT**
My approach was wrong - that only worked because the delimiters were spaces (not the case in my real scenario). This is a better approach:

```
String input = "1.fish.2.fish.red.sheep.blue.sheep";
Pattern animal = Pattern.compile("\\.*(fish|sheep)\\.*");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);

int endOfLastMatch = 0;
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    sc.useDelimiter(animal);
    String nextMatch = sc.next();

    int startOfCurrentMatch = sc.match().start(0);
    if (endOfLastMatch > 0) {
        System.out.println(new String(input.getBytes(), endOfLastMatch, startOfCurrentMatch - endOfLastMatch)); 
    }

    System.out.println(nextMatch);
    endOfLastMatch = sc.match().end();
}

if (endOfLastMatch < input.length()) {
    System.out.println(new String(input.getBytes(), endOfLastMatch, input.length() - endOfLastMatch));  
}
```

Output:

```
1
.fish.
2
.fish.
red
.sheep.
blue
.sheep
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead:

```
String input = "1 fish 2 fish red sheep blue sheep";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*(fish|sheep)\\s*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input)

while (matcher.find()) {
     System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

In this code, `matcher.group(1)` returns the value matched by group 1 in the regex, in this case `(fish|sheep)`. You can make groups by enclosing with parenthesis. You can also get group 0 which returns the whole match.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I need both the delimiter and the split content - I don't think this gives me the split content. I figured out it can be done using `next(Pattern)` in Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for Scanner.findInLine() method

```
    String input = "1 fish 2 fish red sheep blue sheep";
    Pattern delim = Pattern.compile("\\s*(fish|sheep)\\s*");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(delim);
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(s.next());
        System.out.println(s.findInLine(delim));
    }
    s.close();
```